# Not installing Composer successfully

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php

I'm attempting to install *Composer* on my Mac for the first time so that I can use it to work with *Laravel* and this is what I did:

1. Went to getcomposer.org
2. Executed `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
3. Received a message that composer was installed successfully.
4. Executed `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
5. Was asked for password and typed in the administrator password.
6. Received `mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory`.

I tried following [the tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-laravel-4--net-28614) to get it loaded for Laravel and can not figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point it out for me please?

Comment: Why would you move composer after installing it ? Follow the installing instructions on get-composer.com, not a tutorial video.

Comment: If you mv, your current folder must contain the file you want to move.

Answer (score 2):

this is not a composer installing issue, the folder `/usr/local/bin` doesn't exist.

You would have to create it first:

```
mkdir /usr/local/bin -p # -p stands for creating parent directories if needed
```

Comment: Is there a better place for it.

Comment: You could put in in your home bin : ~/bin